# ProgressMonitorInputStream doesn't pop up

Tags: java, stream

This is a sever and its receiving a file from a client. It receives the complete file but the progress bar doesn't show up. I am using ProgressInputStream. Here is the piece of code where I am using SwingWorker to create a new thread for progress bar.

```
SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>()
        {
            protected Void doInBackground()
            {
                try {
                    ss = new ServerSocket(port);
                    s = ss.accept();
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(FileName));
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(frame,"Receiving",dis);
                    pmis.getProgressMonitor().setMillisToPopup(10);

                    while(pmis.read(bytes) > 0)
                    {
                        fos.write(bytes);
                    }


                    ss.close();
                    fos.close();




                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

It only pops up 'if it's taking a while'.

NB:

1. Your copy loop is wrong. It should be:

   ```
   while ((count = pmis.read(bytes)) > 0)
   {
       fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
   }
   ```

where `count` is obviously an `int`.

2. You don't need the `DataInputStream`.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't pop up. I have already tried sending 700+ MB file but no luck. I have also already set popup time to 10 milliseconds. `pmis.getProgressMonitor().setMillisToPopup(10);`

Comment: Try calling `setMaximum()` instead, if you have any idea ahead of time how large the file is.

Comment: I think the problem is that `FileOutputStream` need to be closed in order to show the pop up progress bar but I can't close the `FileOutputStream` because the data is being stored through this stream. I don't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible. The `ProgressMonitorInputStream` does not know the output stream from a hole in the ground.